# Unable to boot Debian Hurd in Virtual Box due to missing hd0s1

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, debian

I'm trying to setup a [Debian Hurd](https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/) test machine to duplicate a privately reported issue on the platform. According to the [README.txt](http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports-cd/hurd-i386/current/YES_REALLY_README.txt):

> To give Debian GNU/Hurd a try, it is probably easier to simply run the
>   preinstalled image, which is provided here:
>
> ```
> $ wget http://ftp.debian-ports.org/debian-cd/hurd-i386/current/debian-hurd.img.tar.xz
> $ tar xJf debian-hurd.img.tar.xz
> ```
>
> ...
>
> It can also be run in virtualbox, by first converting to VDI format :
>
> ```
>   $ VBoxManage convertfromraw debian-hurd*.img debian-hurd.vdi --format vdi
> ```
>
> You can then just log in as root without a password...

I fetched and unpacked `debian-hurd.img.tar.xz`. Then I created a new Linux 32-bit VM, and used `debian-hurd.vdi` as the disk.

After working through the process, the machine encounters an error during boot. The error occurs during regular boot and recovery boot. The error is:

```
start ext2fs: ext2fs: device:hd0s1: No such device or address
```

According to [GNU Hurd | VirtualBox | Installation](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/running/virtualbox.html) on the Debian wiki, this could be caused by a SATA controller rather than and IDE controller. Unfortunately, the selection for a new IDE controller is greyed out, and there is no apparent way to add one (SATA is available).

Why am I receiving the error, and how can I fix it?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting "Other"  and "other" on the iirc in the 2 drop-down box selections.  I'm running VBox 5.1.12.  I specifically did not select Linux, because I don't know what assumptions VBox makes for optimization for Linux.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to try USING the image, you will probably want to use the VBox modifymedium command to resize the image to at least 6GB.  I started with the original image, installed the recommended development tools, and did a dependency build for emacs and firefox.  At that point I had less than 400MB free on the 3GB partition.  Once you have the image resized, you will need to boot the VM with a Gnu Parted image to resize your partitions.  Make sure you put the swap partition back on an extended partition as it was orginally so you don't have to edit fstab to get swap working.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by turning off the virtual machine, going to Machine settings, Storage - removing the downloaded vdi from "Controller: SATA", and adding it instead to the IDE controller, at "Controller: IDE". Then the system will find the hard drive in the correct place.